# Define a schemaLocation when serializing with XStream

Tags: java, xstream

When serializing based on a Java object, is it possible to define a schemaLocation to use for the produced XML?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no replies to this question and since I've already worked around this myself, I am answering my own question. I have simply replaced the root XML element with a hard coded one. XStream doesn't seem to have support for this kind of this, from what I've checked.